# How can I remove some empty closing and opening divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working with some HTML markup that I can't change, and in some instances on particular pages it breaks a layout. What I need to do is remove  - using empty() or remove() or some other jQuery function - the tags commented below `</div>` and `<div>`.

Can I do this with jQuery?
How can I select those two tags?

```
...
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        
        </div> // Remove this closing div
        <div>  // Remove this opening div
        
        <form class="cart" action="example.com" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <div class="wc-pao-addons-container">
...
```

Comment: basically you can't do it in a node scope... you would have to get text, edit it and then create elements all again or move elements that are outside desired div to the previous div

Comment: Thanks. What if the `<div>` tag had a class? Could I then remove it and the previous `</div>`?

Comment: sure, you can do it the same way or simply by accessing the dom node

Comment: OK, how do I do that?

Comment: If your issue has to do with layout perhaps look into the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo selector in CSS. You could just `display: none` them all. Depends on how your layout breaks